# How to Identify Dynamically created window/buttons in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am creating a series of buttons(Or windows) etc on RUN time.

Now how do i identify when user clicks on these buttons?

Answer (score 1):

HI,

I did an R&D on wx.Event(GetEventObject) and found out that i can get object details. 
SO i solved my problem using this.